# Get Cursor position of a string by matching to set Spinner position

Tags: android, cursor-position

I'm getting the custom ringtone ID by caller and basically I want to do a setSelection(); to my spinner with that ringtone but I can't figure out how to match positions..

What I've tried is to match a string "Ringtone Name" to find it's position in a Spinner from it's cursor. Am I going about it the right way? Or is there an easier way to match ringtone ie:content://media/internal/audio/media/72 to the position in the spinner?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        mRingtoneManager2 = new RingtoneManager(this); //adds ringtonemanager
        mRingtoneManager2.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE); //sets the type to ringtones
        mRingtoneManager2.setIncludeDrm(true); //get list of ringtones to include DRM

        mCursor2 = mRingtoneManager2.getCursor(); //appends my cursor to the ringtonemanager

        startManagingCursor(mCursor2); //starts the cursor query

        String[] from = {mCursor2.getColumnName(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX)}; // get the list items for the listadapter could be TITLE or URI

        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1}; //sets the items from above string to listview
        // create simple cursor adapter
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
          new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mCursor2, from, to );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // get reference to our spinner
        s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner1);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);
                getValue(mCursor2);
        s.setSelection(posid);
        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            }

    public String getValue(Cursor cursor) {
            String posid = "Loopy Lounge";
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                posid = cursor.getString(0);
            }
            return;
        }
```